# What is the best practice for using same controller on page multiple times

Tags: angularjs

When you use `ng-controller` to assign a controller to a element on your DOM it only works inside that element. For example:

```
<section ng-controller="ExampleCtrl as example">
    <h1>Example Controller Works Here</h1>
    {{example.item}}
</section>

<section>
    <h1>But Not Here</h1>
    {{example.item}} <!-- Nothing -->
</section>
```

However if a controller is assigned to a directive the controller works anywhere on a page that directive is used. For example:

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', function(){
    return {
        ...
        controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'example'
    };
});

<section>
    <div example-directive>
        <h1>Example Controller Works Here</h1>
        {{example.item}}
    </div>
</section>

<section>
     <h1>And Example Controller Works Here Too</h1>
     {{example.item}}
</section>
```

I am wondering if I am using a controller in a directive and need to access it on a different section of the page is it ok to just rely on the directive, or is it better to declare it again?

```
<section>
    <div example-directive>
    ...
</section>

<section ng-controller="ExampleCtrl as example">
    ...
</section>
```

Also if I do declare it again does that cause any problems with overlapping functionality of the same controller?

I'm not asking about what makes the code cleaner or easier to read. I understand there is the danger of functionality of other elements on the page breaking if I remove the directive and how this get's away from the medullar design of Angular. I'm wondering, from a strictly functional perspective, are there dangers to either approach.

Comment: In general, it's best to keep directives self contained, and not leak functionality through the controller.  It is also not a good practice to have a controller which has functionality to support multiple components, e.g. a directive and a page template.  Your examples are too generic to give specific solutions, but if you are finding that you need some piece of functionality a directive is providing *outside* the directive, that's a code smell.

Comment: in case of this controller which is only on one of two `<section>` elements, is there some reason it couldn't be moved up to the element that wraps both sections?

Comment: I'm not leaking the functionality of the directive. Angular is doing that. I have items which are very similar and reusing a controller just for that functionality makes sense for my code. I am wondering if this leakage is ok. I could wrap an entire area and apply the controller to it, then remove the controller assignment from my directive. But I would rather leave it assigned to the directive. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, no.  This is not something that angular is doing, this is how you have chosen to implement the features angular provides, but this choice isn't a good idea.  Again, without more specific code, this is all conjecture, but plenty of style guides warn against this mixing concerns.

Comment: Obviously the functionality is leaking outside of the directive. If it wasn't then you wouldn't be able to use it. So it is something that is happening in Angular. I understand keeping things modular and separate. However, there are situations when it makes sense to reuse code and controllers. I'm not interested in turing this into a debate about whether my code is clean or not. The examples I provided are not my code. They are examples. I am asking if it is ok to not call the controller again or does it need to be called again. And if I do call it again could that cause problems.

Comment: Maybe someone else can provide a different perspective.  My take on this is that using the same controller more than once is wrong.  Move the re-usable logic into a service.